# How can I add the dots into numpy.ndarray output?

Tags: python, numpy, data-science

Given two lists of 1s and 0s (1 represents the true label, and 0 represents the false false) of the same length, output a 2darrary of counts, each cell is defined as follows

Top left: Predicted true and actually true (True positive)
Top right: Predicted true but actually false (False positive)
Bottom left: Predicted false but actually true (False negative)
Bottom right: Predicted false and actually false (True negative)

Sample Input

```
1 1 0 0
1 0 0 0
```

Sample Output

```
[[1., 0.],
[1., 2.]]
```

My code outputs:

```
[[1 0]
 [1 2]]
```

Where can I get those dots??? Don't care about commas, i don't know why, but the answer without them is correct.

My code:

```
import numpy as np

y_true = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
y_pred =  [int(x) for x in input().split()]
y_true = np.array(list(map(lambda x: 0 if x == 1 else 1, y_true)))
y_pred = np.array(list(map(lambda x: 0 if x == 1 else 1, y_pred)))
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
print(confusion_matrix(y_pred, y_true))
```

Comment: Commas are part of a list display.  The print display of a numpy array omits them, to help distinguish an array from a list.  That's just a visual thing.  The dot though indicates floats, as opposed integers.  That's determined by the array's `dtype`.  Spend some time reading `numpy` basics; don't jump into "data-science" and `sklearn" without some programming basics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dots there are because those numbers are floating points. You'll need to add `.astype(float)`:

```
print(confusion_matrix(y_pred, y_true).astype(float))
```